# Override one value in properties file

Tags: ant, replace

I have a **properties** file:

***custom.properties***

the content of this properties file is:

```
id=sf2j2345kkklljhlaasfsdfafsf543
name=SOME_NAME
```

The value of `id` is a long random string.

I want to make an **Ant** script to **replace/over-write** the value of `id` to another one, I tried with Ant `<replace>` syntax:

```
<target name="change-id">
      <replace file="custom.properties" token="id" value="aaa" />
</target>
```

I run ant change-id , the content of the properties file becomes:

```
aaa=sf2j2345kkklljhlaasfsdfafsf543
name=SOME_NAME
```

That's the key "`id`" get replaced instead of its value. But I need to replace the value to "**aaa**" , how to achieve this in Ant?

**Please do not recommend me to** set `token` to `id`'s random value, because that value is random generated and put there. I only want to over-write the random value of "`id`" by Ant script, how to achieve this?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using `replaceregexp` task. Try to do it like in this example

conf.ini (utf-8)

```
aaa=sf2j2345kkklljhlaasfsdfafsf543
name=SOME_NAME
```

build.xml

```
<project name="regexp.replace.test" default="test">

    <target name="test">
        <replaceregexp file="conf.ini" match="^aaa=.*" replace="aaa=newId" encoding="UTF-8" />
    </target>

</project>
```

I don't know exactly if this regular expression is correct but this is the way you can do it.

Comment: Seems the regular expression is not correct, I tried, and the content of my properties file is unchanged.

Comment: In which encoding your file is encoded? As I wrote, I've tested it on utf-8 and it works. It doesn't really matter that it doesn't work. The idea is that you should use `<replaceregexp/>` task to change some strange text in file, like `sdgf346tergrth`. Regular expression is the best solution for this kind of problem.

Comment: Hi, After I changed from match="^aaa=.*" to match="aaa=.*", it works. The problem is about "^" in regular expression.

Comment: Thanks. If my answer was solution of your problem you can mark it as 'helpful'.