# Override One Property in a .targets file

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild

**Background:** I have several solutions with roughly 300 C++ projects across them, most of them shared. We are using Visual Studio 2013 and have a build script that compiles all of the projects in the correct order, ensuring dependencies are resolved ahead of time. Our development/engineering team builds all of the code through the build script and then attempts to debug using Visual Studio 2013.

**Issue:** The "build then debug" process results in Visual Studio telling us that the Projects are out of date. This stems from the ProjectEvaluationFingerprint property (in Line 39 Microsoft.CppBuild.targets) including a `$(SolutionDir)` in the output file. The [recommended fix from Microsoft](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/772826/projects-just-built-in-another-solution-are-out-of-date) suggests removing the `$(SolutionDir)` from the file. As our developers tends to transition back and forth between projects, I do not want to manually change this .targets file on every developer's machine (and remember to change it back when they leave the project). I would like to override the property in the .vcxproj by using a .targets file explicitly for this.

The property in Microsoft.CppBuild.targets looks like:

```
<!-- Global up-to-date check support -->
<PropertyGroup>
   <ProjectEvaluationFingerprint>$(Configuration)|$(Platform)|$(SolutionDir)|$(ProjectEvaluationFingerprint)</ProjectEvaluationFingerprint>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Generally, I have been following Microsoft's [How to: Use the Same Target in Multiple Project Files](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171464.aspx).  I have created a .targets file (`test.targets`) that contains the following code (*note the TEST text was to test evaluation of the property in both the build script and building the project in Visual Studio*):

```
<Project ToolsVersion="12.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
<PropertyGroup>
    <ProjectEvaluationFingerprint>$(Configuration)|$(Platform)|TEST|$(ProjectEvaluationFingerprint)</ProjectEvaluationFingerprint>
</PropertyGroup>
```

I then import it using the following line in the .vcxproj

```
<Import Project="..\..\Config\VSPropertySheets\test.targets" />
```

The project.lastbuildstate file now reads:

```
#TargetFrameworkVersion=v4.0:PlatformToolSet=v120_xp:EnableManagedIncrementalBuild=false:VCToolArchitecture=Native32Bit
Debug|Win32|D:\views\devbranch\Products\SLN\|Debug|Win32|TEST|
```

It is appending the new ProjectEvaluationFingerprint to the existing one, so it is not overriding (I can understand this to a degree, but I'm no MSBuild expert).

**Question:** How can I override this one property using a .targets file? Do I need to use a [replaceregexp  task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15406712/override-one-value-in-properties-file) or do I have an easier option?

Answer (score 3):

You can override this property, but you have to be careful about two things:

- the new setting you want is this:

  `<ProjectEvaluationFingerprint>$(Configuration)|$(Platform)|TEST/ProjectEvaluationFingerprint>`

  Note the removal of `$(ProjectEvaluationFingerprint)`, which would contain the previous value of this tag
- the location where you put the import is important: you will want to put it at the very end of your project (i.e. after the `Microsoft.CppBuild.targets` import).

Concretely:

> use_custom_fingerprint.targets
>   
>       `<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
>           <PropertyGroup>
>               <ProjectEvaluationFingerprint>$(Configuration)|$(Platform)</ProjectEvaluationFingerprint>
>           </PropertyGroup>
>       </Project>`
>
> project.vcxproj
>   
>       `<Project ...>
>          ...
>          <Import Project="$(VCTargetsPath)\Microsoft.Cpp.targets" />
>          <ImportGroup Label="ExtensionTargets">
>          </ImportGroup>
>          <Import Project="use_custom_fingerprint.targets" />
>       </Project>`

Note that I also tried the extension .props and this worked just the same.

Note: The new import after importing `Microsoft.CppBuild.targets.$(Platform).user.props` is **not** sufficient, it **must** be after `Microsoft.CppBuild.targets`.

Disclaimer: tried in Visual Studio 2015

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. I was able to progress a step further than you, but I still haven't a full solution.

The reason why you have now the old fingerprint appended to the new one without solution dir is your line

```
<ProjectEvaluationFingerprint>$(Configuration)|$(Platform)|TEST|$(ProjectEvaluationFingerprint)</ProjectEvaluationFingerprint>
```

The

```
$(ProjectEvaluationFingerprint)
```

Holds the old fingerprint, so just remove this part from the value for ProjectEvaluationFingerprint and your lastbuildstate will have the desired value.

Sadly now (at least for me) Visual Studio always thinks the fingerprint is wrong and will re-link the project with every compile, not only when switching sln file.

I removed the line from the props sheet and the up-to-date check works again as expected as long as solution directory doesn't change. I then modified the Microsoft.CppBuild.targets directly and this works: No more "not up-to-date" projects, even when switching solution directory.

Comment: This fingerprint simply is written to the '.lastbuildstate' file in the tlog directory of your project (normally `$(IntermediateDirectory)\$(ProjectName).tlogs`) after a successful build, then read back in during the fast up-to-date check to determine if it has changed. Are you sure it's the fingerprint causing the up to date check to fail? What does the [log](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsproject/archive/2009/07/21/enable-c-project-system-logging.aspx) say?

Comment: Hmm, seems like the CPS trace needs a value higher than 4. I tried 31, which works, but generates a warning about it being too high.

Comment: See the blog post I linked to. You can configure VS to enable the diagnostic trace named 'CPS', which tells you very precisely why the fast up to date check thinks your project is out of date.

Comment: Yes, this I had active, sorry. It was telling me the fingerprint is not matching.

Comment: Ah. Weird. It should work. If you check the .lastbuiltstate file by hand, do any of the lines match your custom fingerprint?

Comment: Yes, the .lastbuildstate files look completely fine with my modified content. It looks as if the changed property is only used when saving the .lastbuildstate but not when building the fingerprint to compare it to

Comment: Oh. That's annoying. I was reading the disassembled code for the up to date check (which uses the property), but I can't find the code that actually writes out that file after a build succeeds. It's possible that code doesn't use the property at all, in which case there's no point modifying the project property.

Comment: However, you could always change the lastbuildstate file by hand (or by script after your automated build) to contain the expected fingerprint. Keep in mind that it's generally very difficult to maintain an up-to-date status when files move, because the dependency logs use full paths (and so a file that used to exist will no longer exist, and the moved file will appear to be "new") -- even if the lastbuildstate is modified, there's several other up-to-date checks that may fail. Worth a try, though!